# Using regex on a vector list in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector with character strings in it.  The vector has over 6000 rivers in it but we can use the following as an example:

```
Names <- Baker R, Colorado R, Missouri R
```

I am then matching these river names to a list that contains their full names. As an example, the other list contains names such as:

```
station_nm <- North Creek River, Baker River at Wentworth, Lostine River at Baker Road, Colorado River at North Street, Missouri River
```

In order to find the full names of the stations for the river names in "Names" I have:

```
station_nm <- grep(paste(Names, collapse = "|"), ALLsites$station_nm, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

Continuing with the example, this returns: Baker River at Wentworth, Lostine River at Baker Road, Colorado River at North Street, Missouri River.  It does not return North Creek River, as this is not listed in the "Names" vector.  This is what I want.

However, I want to restrict the rivers that it returns to only Baker River at Wentworth, Colorado River at North Street, Missouri River.  I don't want to include names for which there is something before it, i.e. Lostine River at Baker Road.

I believe this should involve some sort of negative look behind but I don't know how to write this with the vector "Names".

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to prepend the values in `Names` with a `^` meaning "has to start with":

```
grep(paste0("^", Names, "iver", collapse = "|"), station_nm,
     ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "Baker River at Wentworth" "Colorado River at North Street" "Missouri River"
```